# php mysql connection does not show results why

Tags: php, mysql

this is driving me crazy why aren't the results showing???

```
function runSQL($rsql) {

    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','xxx','xxx') or die ("Error: could not connect to database");
    $db = mysql_select_db('xxx');

    $result = mysql_query($rsql) or die ("Error in query: $query. " . mysql_error());

    return $result;
    mysql_close($connect);
}

$rsql = "SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE subscriptionID = 6 ";
runSQL($rsql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['subscription'];
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: I have added source formatting; feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't process your result ...

You call your function (runSQL) to execute the query and it returns the resultset, but you don't catch the resultset to work with it.

Use `$result = runSQL($rsql);` instead of `runSQL($rsql);`.

Also note that `mysql_close($connect);` is never called in your code, it's unreachable as the return occurs first.

Comment: Also, keep the connection to MySQL open, don't open&close for every query.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the connection before doing `mysql_fetch_(assoc|array|etc)` on it, those functions will likely fail. The connection should not be closed until you're done interacting with the database, including reading the data.